# List indices must be integers or slices, not float in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I don't know where I'm going wrong that I'm not able to create the graph.

Repository: https://github.com/Anderson-Andre-P/Uber-Data-Analysis

```py
plt.scatter(
    embedding[:, 0],
    embedding[:, 1],
    c=[sns.color_palette()[x] for x in df.Monday.map({"Monday": 0, "Tuesday": 1, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 3, "Friday": 4, "Saturday": 5, "Sunday": 6})])

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.title('UMAP projection of the Uber dataset', fontsize=24);
```

[Print google collab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCMDN.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your code looks strange.  Maybe you could try `plt.scatter(embedding[:, 0], embedding[:, 1], cmap='Set1', c=df.Monday.map({"Monday": 0, "Tuesday": 1, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 3, "Friday": 4, "Saturday": 5, "Sunday": 6}))`? Are you using recent matplotlib and pandas versions?

Comment: Possibly your `df.Monday` contains one or more values that are not literally in the dictionary.  In that case `df.Monday.map(....)` returns `NaN` for those values, and makes the datatype of the result `float` instead of `integer` (integers can't be `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that the `x` that is got from iterator is of type `float`. It should be `int`.

I suggest you to rewrite your code to extract variables. The code will be much more readable and debuggable too.

Comment: As this isn't really answering the question, it would be better if you added it as a comment, not as an answer post.

Comment: I disagree. That is the right problem which entails an obvious code change.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)